# Connection between RabbitMQ and MassTransit

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, masstransit

Okay so I have the following problem, this is just a basic test-program but I'm already struggling. I'm very new to this and haven't found a similar scenario yet.

Basically, I need to publish messages to a specific queue (more down the line, but the point is we need a fixed topology) and as far as I understand things, I can't do that with MassTransit.

My idea now was to publish messages to a queue using bare RabbitMQ and then reading from that Queue with MassTransit.

So I got 2 very basic console applications now with TestPublisher being the publisher using RabbitMQ only and TestSubscriber being the consumer using MassTransit.

**TestPublisher:**

*Program.cs*

```
using System;
using RabbitMQ.Client;
using System.Text;
using TestPublisher;

class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = "localhost", VirtualHost = "testvhost" };
        using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
        using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
        {


            var message = new TestMessage(){ message = "Test"};
            var body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message.message);

            channel.BasicPublish(exchange: "MTQueue", routingKey: "MTQueue", basicProperties: null, body: body);
            Console.WriteLine(" [x] Sent {0}", message);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(" Press [enter] to exit.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

*TestMessage.cs*

```
using Contracts;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestPublisher
{
    class TestMessage : MessageDelivery
    {
        public string message { get; set; }

    }
}
```

**TestSubscriber**

*Program.cs*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MassTransit;
using MassTransit.Log4NetIntegration.Logging;

namespace TestSubscriber
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Log4NetLogger.Use();
            var bus = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(x =>
            {
                var host = x.Host(new Uri("rabbitmq://localhost/testvhost/"), h => { });
                x.ReceiveEndpoint(host, "MTQueue", e => e.Consumer<TestMessageConsumer>());
            });
            bus.Start();
            Console.ReadKey();
            bus.Stop();

        }
    }
}
```

*TestMessageConsumer.cs*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Contracts;
using MassTransit;

namespace TestSubscriber
{
    class TestMessageConsumer : IConsumer<MessageDelivery>
    {
        public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<MessageDelivery> context)
        {
            Console.Write("TEXT: " + context.Message);
            Console.Write(" VERARBEITET: " + DateTime.Now);
            Console.WriteLine(" (" + System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + ")");
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    }
}
```

**Contracts**

*Contracts.cs*

```
using System;

namespace Contracts
{
    public interface MessageDelivery
    {
        string message { get; }
    }
}
```

I can publish to the queue with TestPublisher without problems, the message will be in the correct queue, using the RabbitMQ Management interface to verify.

My problem now, as RabbitMQ will only let me publish byte-arrays with BasicPublish, is that I can't get the message from the queue with TestSubscriber, as the consumer expects a message of the type MessageDelivery and won't let me configure the ConsumeContext or IConsumer to listen for byte[]

I'm really stuck here and can't find a solution, neither on RabbitMQ side nor on the MassTransit side.

Comment: Basically, we need to know what you did, what failed, and what you are trying to do (what does success look like). If you really don’t know what you are doing, there are many tutorials you should check out, then post a more specific question.

Comment: as i said, i published the "Hello World!" message into the queue with TestPublisher using only RabbitMQ. Inspecting the queue with the RabbitMQ Management UI it shows that the message was indeed published to the queue. What failed now is the consume part with MassTransit. It's a very simple program as you can see and basically everything TestSubscriber should do upon startup, is get the message from the queue and write it on the commandline. However when I start it up, no message gets shown and inspectin with management ui, there is no message in the MTQueue queue anymore but rather in the

Comment: MTQueue_error queue with following output: MT-Fault-ExceptionType: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException MT-Fault-Message: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: T. Path '', line 0, position 0.   And I cant for the live of me get TestSubscriber to consume my message.

Answer (score 1):

MassTransit uses JSON serialization and it expects messages in a pre-defined format. The use-case that you describe is not what MassTransit is made for However, if you want to do it, please check the Interoperability section in the documentation: http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/advanced/interoperability.html

Here is the example message from there (JSON payload):

```
{
    "destinationAddress": "rabbitmq://localhost/input_queue",
    "headers": {},
    "message": {
        "value": "Some Value",
        "customerId": 27
    },
    "messageType": [
        "urn:message:MassTransit.Tests:ValueMessage"
    ]
}
```

Comment: I was just going to post this, yep. The message must be property serialized, and the ContentType (in basic properties) should also be set (but the default is to try to use JSON).

Comment: I see, thanks for clarifying that. However, BasicPublish in RabbitMQ will only let me publish data if type byte[], is there any workaround for this?

Comment: @nico you just use something like `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message));`

Comment: you can also look at what MassTransit does, via the source: https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/develop/src/MassTransit/Serialization/JsonMessageSerializer.cs